# How to redirect to external url onClick? in React

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redirect, react-router, external-url

I'm using react-router which means i'm storing routes in `app.tsx` file.

I have cards components that need to redirect to an external url `onClick`.

**So my question is** how to redirect `onClick` on card component using the external url example: [www.test.com](http://www.test.com) and give to that url two query strings `a=xxx` and `b=xxx`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [React-Router External link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42914666/react-router-external-link)

Comment: Thank you, but i need to use query strings in my external url so here i cant find that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can redirect to an external URL with dynamic query strings with [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals):

```
const onClick = () => {
  location.href = `www.test.com/?a=${queryA}&b=${queryB}`
}
```

where `queryA` and `queryB` are your dynamic injected query strings

Answer (score 6):

You can also use [window.open()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open)

> The **open()** method of the **Window** interface loads a specified resource
> into a new or existing browsing context (that is, a tab, a window, or
> an iframe) under a specified name.

### Parameters:

> **url:** a string indicating the URL or path of the resource to be loaded. If an empty string ("") is specified or this parameter is omitted, a blank page is opened into the targeted browsing context.
>
> **target (optional)**: a string, without whitespace, specifying the name of the browsing context the resource is being loaded into. If the name doesn't identify an existing context, a new context is created and given the specified name. The special target keywords, _self, _blank, _parent, and _top, can also be used.

### Example

Once you click the card the external link will open on a new tab.

```
const url = 'https://www.test.com'

function Card(){
  return(
    <div 
      className='card-wrapper'
      onClick={() => window.open(url, '_blank')}  
    >
      <span>Some content here</span>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Is that what you need?

```
const onClick = () => {
    location.href = 'http://<location>/?a=1';
}
```

Answer (score 3):

`location.href` not works ?

Facing this erros

```js
Unexpected use of 'location' no-restricted-globals
```

if you are using **React ^18**, need you add `window` before location

```
let url = 'https://www.external.url/'

<Button onClick={() => { window.location.href = url; } }>
   Click Here
</Button>
```