# Open new React app when new router selected

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I have a button, this is called `game`. When this is clicked, routing is triggered and you are redirected to `localhost:3000/game`. However, I do not want to be redirected to a new page, but to a new React app. This app is in a different folder and was regenerated with `npx create-react-app game`. Is there an option to go to the new React app with this button click? The React app does not need to be started but only opened.

So when I click the button in my `localhost:3000` the React App Game should open with the routing e.g. `localhost:4000/game`. Later, both React apps run on the same domain, for example, `my-react-app.com` and `my-react-app.com/game`

Is there such a thing? If so, how can I create it?
Haven't found anything so far.

Comment: I think you can find your answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42914666/react-router-external-link

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use JavaScript functionality with `window.location.href`
For example:

```
 const redirect = () => {
     window.location.href = "http://localhost:4000/game";
     };
```

Then call the function, for example using a button:

```
<button onClick={redirect}> Redirect </button>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to redirect to whole new port (i.e Other project) you need to use js or html `href` or `window.open` to do that there nothing here to use router. Router is used to navigate through the app or project not the whole web. thanks