# Warning: Expected `onClick` listener to be a function, instead got a value of `string` type

Tags: reactjs

```
const TextInfoShiftBox: FunctionComponent<TextInfoShiftBoxInterface> = () => {
  
  const [stateArrow, setStateArrow] = useState(false);
  
  const handlerCollapseInfo = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    setStateArrow(!stateArrow)
  };
  
  return (
    <AreaContainer>
      <div className='info-shift-box'>
        <Icon onClick={(e) => handlerCollapseInfo(e)} className='arrow-icon' size='20px' icon={stateArrow ? "be-110" : "be-030"} />
        <h3>Info</h3><Icon className='warm-icon' size='24px' icon={"bd-150"} />
      </div>
      <div>
      <b>text</b>
      <LinkContainer>
        <Link className='ref' text=' acá.' onClick="www.google.com.ar" type='red' />
      </ LinkContainer>
        <span className='info-shift-box-client'>
          &nbsp; other text.
          {stateArrow ? ' text' : ''}
        </span>
      </div>
    </ AreaContainer>
  )
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [React-Router External link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42914666/react-router-external-link)

Answer (score 1):

```
onClick="www.google.com.ar"
```

The above is returning a string, if you want the link to go somewhere you need to use the `to` method:

```
<Link className='ref' text=' acá.' to="https://www.google.com.ar" type='red' />
```