# Redirect url in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
 Api_res : {
    payment_url: "https://secure-global.paytabs.com/payment/page/5B36B80182E417D3CAC11"
    redirect_url: "https://secure-global.paytabs.com/payment/page/5B36B80182E417D3CAC119BF"
    }
```

For example, I got a redirect url in api response, but how will I use that url to go to that link, in react js?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42914666/react-router-external-link?

Comment: would you use react-router?

Answer (score 0):

Browser navigation usually involves modifying the `location` of the window /document. To achieve this, you can either make use of an external library such as react-router (pointed out in the other comments) or you can use native methods such as changing the `window.location.href`.
If you prefer going for `react-router` check out the [stackoverflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42914666/react-router-external-link) which @anthino12 shared above, else if you opt for the second method check out the MDN docs linked below to understand more about it and the other possible ways to achieve the same result.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/location