# External link not working when using LINK from react router dom

Tags: javascript, reactjs

This is the code i have used for redirection.

It is redirecting to

```
http://localhost:3000/something/https://example.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/123456789-Privacy-Policies
```

instead of

```
https://example.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/123456789-Privacy-Policies
```

```
<Link
  to={{
    pathname:
      "https://example.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/123456789-Privacy-Policies"
  }}
  target="_blank"
>
  <Button variant="contained" className="py-1 px-2">
    <i className="ri-upload-2-line pe-2"></i> Apply
  </Button>
</Link>
```

Comment: checkout the answer : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42914666/react-router-external-link

Answer (score 0):

I think react-router attempt assuming relative path,
if you want absolute link you can use directly tag `a` instead of `Link` component.

```js
<a href="https://example.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/123456789-Privacy-Policies" target="_blank">
  <Button
    variant="contained"
    className="py-1 px-2">
      <i className="ri-upload-2-line pe-2"></i> Apply
  </Button>
</a>
```

Answer (score -2):

Next.js `Link` is designed to be used only as a internal routing tool, because it works with next.js router.
For external link use standart anchor tag `<a href...`

Comment: react router dom