# Trying to switch between local and public webpage while looping through data

Tags: html, reactjs, jsx

At the moment, I am trying to list projects on a website in a grid. Some of them link to another page on the site and others link to another domain page. At the moment I am using React-Router's 'Link' to go from one page to another, however this doesn't work when going to a page outside of the domain. In the JSON file, I check for the 'url' variable which returns either the URL if its public or 'project-page' if it is local. I can't figure out how to differentiate between the two in JSX; is there a work around while still utilizing the JSON file?

```
<div className="projects">
    {projectData.map((projectDetail, index) => {
        return(
            <div className='project-card'>
                <Link to={projectDetail.url}>
                    <img src={require('./images/icons/' + projectDetail.alt + '.jpg')} alt={projectDetail.title}/>
                    <h3>{projectDetail.title}</h3>
                    <p>{projectDetail.subtext}</p>
                </Link>
            </div>
        )
    })}
</div>
```

Comment: This question has nothing to do with JSON. JSON is just how you store the data in the file. By the time you have `projectData`, you're in the realm of good ole arrays and objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, to differentiate you can check the content of the `projectDetail.url` you are retrieving from that JSON in your javascript file, if that matches your domain (your website - having a `project-page` as you mention) or is it an external domain. You can also set a flag value in your json file. For each project set a value (e.g externalUrl: 1 or 0) and then check if projectDetail.externalUrl is 1 (it contains an external link). Then, maybe try the following for external domains:

```
<Link to={{ pathname: "external URL" }} target="_blank" />
```

In your case:

```
<Link to={{ pathname: projectDetail.url }} target="_blank" />
```

See this answer for detailed information: [React-Router External link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62028885/19173329)

**Edit 1**

If Link does not work for external websites, this would probably be related to the version of `react-router` you are using. Actually, to navigate to external websites you can as well use anchort tags `<a>` to redirect. Check what URL your project has and then conditional render a `<Link>` or `<a>`.

```
<a href="www.example.com" target=_blank></a>
```

Comment: Your link points to a question, not an answer. Did you mean https://stackoverflow.com/a/69544983/ ?

Comment: Oh yes, sorry for that. :)

Comment: This is soo close to what I'm trying to do except the link adds to the end of the domain so it takes me to "localhost/work/https://www.example.com". Is there something i can add to this aswell?

Comment: One option would be to use react Route directly: `<Route path='/your-favourite-path' component={() => { window.location.href = 'https://example.com/';  return null;}}/>`

Comment: Secondly, I guess why <Link> is not working is depending on the version of `react-router` you are using, but you can also use `anchor` links directly to redirect to an external website, as you don't need to use react-router to navigate to an external website. `<a target="_blank" href="https://example.com">Policies</a>`. You can check if the url is external or not and then render conditionally `Link` or `<a>`

Comment: Using an if statement to differentiate between anchor or Link works wonders, thank you!!