# Navigate to external link in react js

Tags: reactjs

trying to navigate the users to differrent websites upon registration

```
handleSubmit = () => {
code
if(registered){
Navigate to external link
}
    }
```

Im trying to use `<Link to={{ pathname: 'res.data.storeRegistrationLink' }}/>` but its not working.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [React-Router External link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42914666/react-router-external-link)

Comment: did you try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31079081/programmatically-navigate-using-react-router ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this and let me know if you face any issues.
Here you can use window.location.replace too while i write window.location because it allows the user to go back to the route that redirected them.

```
 handleSubmit = () => {   if(registered){  window.location.href = 'https://google.com';  }}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this code:

```js
window.location.href === `${res.data.storeRegistrationLink}`
```

Answer (score 0):

if you're using react-router-dom you can easily redirect the user after the condition is true like the following:

```
handleSubmit = () => {
    code
    if(registered){
        <Redirect to="/somewhere/else" />
    }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You could maybe use the link tag from react router dom in this way.

```
<Link to='/'></Link>
```

Just but your desired link in the to attribute.

Answer (score 0):

You can use window object for this like below

```
 handleSubmit = () => {
    some code
    if(registered){
    window.open(res.data.storeRegistrationLink, "_blank")
    }
   }
```