# ajax success redirect not working

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

i have a ajax post from my form. when it succeed, i want to redirect to another web page..

What i have now:

```
$.ajax({
        type : 'POST',
        url : '/system/login.php',
        data : formData,
        dataType : 'json',

    success: function(data) {
        if(!data.success){
            if(data.errors.username){
                alert(data.errors.username);
            }

            if(data.errors.password){
                alert(data.errors.password);
            }
            if(data.errors.login){
                alert(data.errors.login);
            }
        }
        else{
            location.href = "http://localhost/me.php"
        }
    },
    error: function(xhr){
     alert(xhr.responseText);
  }
});
```

Is there someone who can help me? because nothing i tried works.

Comment: See specifically [this comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2383401/javascript-setting-location-href-versus-location#comment63865970_2383427) on the DUP answer

Comment: Does it trigger the error function? Because the system/login.php probably doesnt return a 200 OK

Answer (score 1):

change this line

```
location.href = "http://localhost/me.php"
```

to

```
window.location.href='http://localhost/me.php'
```

make sure ajax response is ok

Answer (score 0):

jQuery is not necessary, and window.location.replace(...) will best simulate an HTTP redirect.

window.location.replace(...) is better than using window.location.href, because replace() does not keep the originating page in the session history, meaning the user won't get stuck in a never-ending back-button fiasco.

> If you want to simulate someone clicking on a link, use  location.href
>
> If you want to simulate an HTTP redirect, use location.replace

For example:

```
// similar behavior as an HTTP redirect
window.location.replace("http://localhost/me.php");

// similar behavior as clicking on a link
window.location.href = "http://localhost/me.php";
```