# How to redirect to the signin page and display message in that page

Tags: jquery

In this code, **OTPVerficationHTML()** function having condition that **data.rval == 2**, where it should redirect to **signin** page and display the message in that page only

```
var flag = 0;
   $("#successPrimary").on('click', function(e) {
     e.preventDefault()
     user_name = $('#Login_UserName').val();
     password = $('#Login_Password').val();
     captcha = $('#Login_captcha').val();

     var PostData = {};
     PostData['put'] = true;
     PostData['form_login_username'] = user_name;
     PostData['form_login_password'] = password;
     PostData['form_login_captcha'] = captcha;

     Application.Post("/ajax/ajax_login", PostData, function(data){
        if(data.rval == 1){
          window.location = "/offerletter/index";
          Application.PageAlertBox.Show('Sucess', ['Login Successfully.']);
        }else if(data.rval == 2){
          OTPVerficationHTML()
          Application.PageAlertBox.Show('info', ['Enter OTP to Verify.']);
        }else{
          Application.PageAlertBox.Show('error',[data.Message]);
        }
      });
   });

   var OTPVerficationHTML = function () {
     initial_html = $('#otpfromlogin').html();
     $('#otpfromlogin').empty();
     $('#buttons').empty();
     $('#otpfromlogin').append(final_html);
     $('#Login_UserName').val(user_name);
     $('#Login_UserName').attr('readonly', 'true');
     $('#Login_UserName').focus();
   }

   $('#otpfromlogin').on('click', '#otp-verify', function(e) {
      e.preventDefault()
      otp = $('#form_otp').val();
       var PostData = {};
       PostData['put'] = true;
       PostData['form_login_otp'] = otp;

     Application.Post("/ajax/ajax_loginwithotp", PostData, function(data) {
        if(data.rval == 1) {
            window.location = "/offerletter/index";
            Application.PageAlertBox.Show('Sucess', ['Successfully Loggedin.']);
        } else if(data.rval == 2) {
            window.location = "/signin";
            Application.PageAlertBox.Show('info', ['OTP is Expired, Pleasem login with new OTP.']);
        } else if(data.rval == -4) {
            Application.PageAlertBox.Show('error', ['OTP is Invalid. Please Enter correct OTP.']);
        } else {
            Application.PageAlertBox.Show('error', [data.Message]);
        }
      });
   });
```

It is not displaying the message on signin page. I don't know how to deal with this kind of situation.

Comment: If the redirect is happening to `signin` page then the problem is not your JS code, it's on the `signin` page.

Comment: no brother. how to do that??

Comment: So redirect isn't happening?

Comment: we have to send the message through the current page to signin page

Comment: redirection is working fine. just we have to show the message. that's it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the redirection is working fine, you can change the below code:

```
window.location = "/signin";
```

to

```
window.location = "/signin?q=1";
```

And in your `signin` page, you can receive this using `$_POST['q']`. Based on this value, you can perform next set of activities in your `signin` page.

Answer (score 0):

There are couple of ways doing this using jquery:

**Window.loaction**
Will return the url of the current page. 
when assigned, changes the url of the page to the one assigned and shows it.

```
window.location = "/signin";
```

As the above example

**Window.location.replace**

Navigates to the desired url, without adding record to history.

```
window.location.replace("http://someaddress");
```

**Window.location.assign**

Navigates to the desired url, adding record to history.

```
window.location.assign("http://someaddress");
```

**Window.location.href**

simulating user click.

```
window.location.href = "/signin";
```

There is a [Discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2383401/javascript-setting-location-href-versus-location) Here about whether .location.href is of better use over .location if you are interested.

As the accepted answer stated, get the data using $_POST['q'].