# Why doesn't the redirect work in this case? ( Javascript only! )

Tags: javascript, html, css

In my HTML file i have a form that has the following submit button:

```
<button  id="submit" >Submit</button>
```

In my Javascript file i did the following :

```
window.onload=function(){
    document.getElementById("submit").onclick = form_action;
}

function form_action()
{
    window.location.href="www.google.com";
}
```

So, the submit button redirects to another webpage. ( I  read  some data from a form, but that doesn't matter right now,  and after that i redirect to another page). The thing is, the redirect does not happen at all!

The only way i was able to make it work was by adding : `alert(location.href)` after `window.location.href="www.google.com";` . My guess is that this forces the update of the window?

How do i work around this problem? Why does this occur? Can someone offer some insight?
I want to solve it purely by using Javascript.

I do not wish to modify my HTML file nor use Jquery.

Comment: add `type="button"` to your `<button>` HTML

Comment: @Sacha that will not help.

Comment: This was great! Thanks! It works like a charm!
The question is, why does it work ? 
Why is there a difference from the last time?

Comment: try just `location = "www.google.com"` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2383401/javascript-setting-location-href-versus-location ... or `location.href` without the window

Comment: @ewizard the result is the same; 
Adding the type="button" solved my issue!

Comment: you must continue! :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The default "type" of a `<button>` is "submit". Thus your button was submitting the form it's located in, to whatever URL that form is set to. By adding `type="button"`, the `<button>` will have no built-in action so your JavaScript code will be all that matters.

Comment: Thanks a lot!! Will flag as answer as soon as i can!