# How can I get all the links on a site without using the html code?

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Using python 3. I've been trying to find a way to get links that are on dynamic pages but I'm only getting things in the href and the links I need aren't there.

For example, trying to get the link to a specific tournament from [this](https://www.itftennis.com/en/tournament-calendar/womens-world-tennis-tour-calendar/?startdate=2021-01) page, but they don't appear in the page source. Is this something I can even do with BeautifulSoup or Selenium?

Thanks!

Comment: Hi, Can you post what you have tried. Maybe an example output would be nice as well.

Comment: Maybe the links are not in the page source, but if you inspect the webpage you mentioned, there are <a> tags with the relative link to all tournaments. To get the DOM of the page you should use selenium, not BS.

Answer (score 1):

go to the page and look in :

```
<section class="page-section">
<div class="page-section__inner">
<table class="table">
<tbody>
<tr class="whatson-table__tournament>"
...
```

There is everything you need to build the links yourself.
you won't find the complete URL since they use a JS link builder or Server side controllers.

Answer (score 1):

I had a look at that page and the links are href. BUT, there are other ways that links can work, one can use javascript to also create links. I found this on stackoverflow just to show that it could be difficult to get all the "links":

[Javascript: Setting location.href versus location](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2383401/javascript-setting-location-href-versus-location)

Also, see this: https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_window_location.asp

Answer (score 0):

Try to use parametrized xpath for e.g for your table //tbody/tr[1]/td[1]/a[1] and enstead
tr[1] use tr["i"] where i is iterator in loop. First you will need to get num of rows like //tbody/tr. This will help you fore the tournaments links.