# window.location.href vs window.location.replace vs window.location.assign in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, url, dom, location, difference

What is the difference between

1. `window.location.href="http://example.com";`
2. `window.location.replace("http://example.com");`
3. `window.location.assign("http://example.com");`

I read in many forums that `window.location.assign()` just replaces the current session history and hence back button of browser will not function. However, I am not able to reproduce this.

```
function fnSetVariable() {
    //window.location.href = "http://example.com";
    window.location.replace("http://example.com");
    //window.location.assign("http://example.com");
}

<a onmouseover="fnSetVariable();" 
   href="PageCachingByParam.aspx?id=12" >
   CLICK 
</a>
```

Comment: You can see an older post in the url: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1865837/whats-the-difference-between-window-location-and-window-location-replace hope it will be helpful

Comment: Here’s a better explanation: http://stackoverflow.com/a/847130/96656

Comment: window.location.replace is not working for the local file path (eg: file:///C:/1.html)

Answer (score 224):

These do the same thing:

```
window.location.assign(url);
window.location = url;
window.location.href = url;
```

They simply navigate to the new URL. The `replace` method on the other hand navigates to the URL without adding a new record to the history.

So, what you have read in those many forums is not correct. The `assign` method does add a new record to the history.

Reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/location

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer. It helped me a lot to resolve the browser back button issue.

Comment: @blunderboy: It's the top answer by a landslide anyway, so that wouldn't change a thing.

Comment: So what's the point of `assign()`? From this answer, and the docs, it sounds identical to `location = ...`.

Comment: @Mitya IMHO `assign()` is better, calling a function for a side effect is more readable. Also you can easily mock it for testing.

Comment: I would like to add that Quttera Labs has marked window.location.replace as potentially suspicious.

Answer (score 18):

The part about not being able to use the Back button is a common misinterpretation. window.location.replace(URL) throws out the *top* ONE entry from the page history list, by overwriting it with the new entry, so the user can't easily go Back to that ONE particular webpage. The function does NOT wipe out the *entire* page history list, nor does it make the Back button completely non-functional.

(NO function nor combination of parameters that I know of can change or overwrite history list entries that *you* don't own absolutely for certain - browsers generally impelement this security limitation by simply not even defining any operation that might at all affect any entry other than the *top* one in the page history list. I shudder to think what sorts of dastardly things malware might do if such a function existed.)

If you really want to make the Back button non-functional (probably not "user friendly": think again if that's *really* what you want to do), "open" a brand new window. (You can "open" a popup that doesn't even *have* a "Back" button too  ...but popups aren't very popular these days:-) If you want to keep your page showing no matter what the user does (again the "user friendliness" is questionable), set up a window.onunload handler that just reloads your page all over again clear from the very beginning every time.

Comment: *'NO function nor combination of parameters that I know of can change or overwrite history list entries '* ... Welcome to HTML5

Comment: The inability to change or overwrite browser history entries you don't own is a security rule that's been around for a _long_ time. HTML5 simply continues that rule.

Comment: You missed the point or sarcasm rather. Look up html5 and history

Comment: window.location.replace is not working for the local file path (eg: file:///C:/1.html)

Answer (score 0):

[location](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location), [location.href](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location/href) and [location.assign()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location/assign) can go to the URL adding the record to the history so we can go back to the previous page:

```js
location = "http://example.com";
location.href = "http://example.com";
location.assign("http://example.com");
```

[location.replace()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location/replace) can go to the URL not adding the record to the history so we cannot go back to the previous page:

```js
location.replace("http://example.com");
```