# What is the difference between location.replace and location.href?

Tags: javascript, dom

What is the difference between the two :

```
location.replace(url)
```

and

```
location.href = url
```

I read that the first method stimulates `HTTP redirect` and the second one is similar, to following a web-page by clicking a link.

But I do not understand really,what does that mean.

Comment: possibly duplicate [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1865837/whats-the-difference-between-window-location-and-window-location-replace](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1865837/whats-the-difference-between-window-location-and-window-location-replace)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Difference between window.location.href, window.location.replace and window.location.assign](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7703689/difference-between-window-location-href-window-location-replace-and-window-loca)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`location.replace` doesn't update the browser's history, you can't press the back button, `location.href` is pretty much like clicking on a link.

> The Location.replace()method replaces the current resource with the
>   one at the provided URL. The difference from the assign() method is
>   that after using replace() the current page will not be saved in
>   session History, meaning the user won't be able to use the back button
>   to navigate to it.

Source : [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location.replace)