# passing multiple values through js page redirection code

Tags: javascript

I am trying to send multiple values to another page but its not working here is the code.plz tell me is there any problem in it

```
javascript:location ="addlike.php?userid=" + session "&postid="+id  ;
```

Comment: i just want to know how to send multiple variables to other page through js?

Comment: Is this in javascript code or the `href` of an `a` tag? Also, the answer below has a good point. You need to use + to concatenate the string between every hard coded value and every variable.

Comment: yup the answer below works but i dont want to use href. This is in javascript code i am not using the a tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to redirect somebody to a different location, maybe you can try :

```
document.location.href="addlike.php?userid="+session+"&postid="+id;
```

Note the use of `+` each side of the variable to concat

Comment: document.location.replace("") is a good alternative also. you should read up on the differences [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7703689/difference-between-window-location-href-window-location-replace-and-window-loca)