# input type image click event in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to navigate to another page using jquery

Markup :

```
<input type="image" name="ImageButton1" id="btnCancel" src="../images/btn_cancel.gif" />
```

JS

```
 $('input[type="image"][id^="btnCancel"]').live('click', function () {
        window.location.replace('default.aspx');
 });
```

Page just refreshes, it does not navigate to desired page. when i change `type=button` it works.

How to achieve the same by keeping type as image only ?

Comment: live is deprecated, use on instead of it

Comment: Why 2 attribute selectors for a single element? you can only do it with `$("#btnCancel").`

Comment: input type="image" acts like submit. Replace it with type="button"

Comment: @ArvindBhardwaj : i want to keep image only

Comment: If `type="button"` works, then use it. Since you want to keep the image, style the button in CSS using the image as the background.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$("#btnCancel").on('click', function () {
        window.location.href = 'default.aspx';
});
```

Comment: Why to use `href` over `replace` ?

Comment: Difference is only the way they manipulate browser history: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7703689/difference-between-window-location-href-window-location-replace-and-window-loca

Answer (score 3):

Use preventdefault:

```
$('input#btnCancel').on('click', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        window.location.replace('default.aspx');
 });
```

Answer (score 1):

Us on instead of live...and prevent default to stop the default behaviour.

```
  $(document).on('click','input[type="image"][id^="btnCancel"]',function(e){
       e.preventDefault();
       window.location.replace('default.aspx');
  });
```

live is deprecated