# want to hide first url while URL redirecting to a 3rd url

Tags: php, redirect

There are 3 urls

I want a place a www.url2.com in in a page of www.url1.com and redirect it to www.url3.com (the script will be in www.url2.com)
or
when someone clicks on a link in www.url1.com - it goes to www.url2.com and a php script works and redirects to www.url3.com

The site www.url3.com should not be able to track www.url1.com

www.url3.com should only know about www.url2.com
here is the php script.
Please help me find a way.

**Now I place a goo.gl (links to www.url2.com) link in www.url1.com and takes the user to www.url2.com and there the script takes user to www.url3.com
But www.url3.com still shows the source url as www.url1.com !!! It can track the first url !! how ?**

```
<?php


// change if you wish
$db = 'urls.sw';

// language/style/output variables
$l_nourl        = '<strong>No URL supplied</strong>';
$l_yoururl      = '<strong>Your short url:</strong>';
$l_invalidurl   = '<strong>Invalid URL supplied.</strong>';
$l_createurl    = 'Snip!';



if(!is_writable($db) || !is_readable($db))
{
    die('Cannot write or read from file. Pleae CHMOD the url file to 777');
}

$action = trim($_GET['id']);
$action = (empty($action) || $action == '') ? 'create' : 'redirect';

$valid = "^(https?|ftp)\:\/\/([a-z0-9+!*(),;?&=\$_.-]+(\:[a-z0-9+!*(),;?&=\$_.-]+)?@)?[a-z0-9+\$_-]+(\.[a-z0-9+\$_-]+)*(\:[0-9]{2,5})?(\/([a-z0-9+\$_-]\.?)+)*\/?(\?[a-z+&\$_.-][a-z0-9;:@/&%=+\$_.-]*)?(#[a-z_.-][a-z0-9+\$_.-]*)?\$";

if($action == 'create')
{
    if(isset($_POST['create']))
    {
        $url = trim($_POST['url']);
        if($url == '')
        {
            echo $l_nourl;
        }
        else
        {
            if(eregi($valid, $url))
            {
                $fp = fopen($db, 'a');
                fwrite($fp, "{$url}\r\n");
                fclose($fp);
                $id = count(file($db));
                $dir = dirname($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
                $snippedurl = "http://{$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']}{$dir}/$id";
                echo "$l_yoururl <a href='$snippedurl'>$snippedurl</a>";
            }
            else
            {
                echo $l_invalidurl;
            }
        }
    }
}

if($action == 'redirect')
{
    $urls = file($db);
    $id   = trim($_GET['id']);
    $id   = $id - 1;
    if(isset($urls[$id]))
    {
        header("Location: {$urls[$id]}");
        exit;
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: And what's the current issue?

Comment: @Chay22   – Now I place a goo.gl (links to www.url2.com) link in www.url1.com and takes the user to www.url2.com and there the script takes user to www.url3.com
But www.url3.com still shows the source url as www.url1.com !!! It can track the first url !! how ?

Comment: The server can't set HTTP referrer to the client. I think the javascript `location.href` might help.

Comment: @Chay22 -  Thanks for the solution . can you insert the mentioned code in this script  ? I know little about js

Answer (score 0):

The server can't set HTTP referrer to the client. Use javascript instead

Change

```
header("Location: {$urls[$id]}");
```

to

```
echo "<script>location.href = '".$urls[$id]."';</script>";
```

Suit yourself to get other javascript types redirection [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7703689/difference-between-window-location-href-window-location-replace-and-window-loca)

Comment: @ShijilT What does not working means? No errors given?

Comment: @ShijilT That's weird, I can confirm it works here on my localhost. Try to wrap it as html page, then lets see.