# jquery php form redirction after callback

Tags: php, jquery, redirect, callback

simply put I can't get any redirection to work after my 'insert_callback', here is my code

```
$('#email').focusout(function() {
var email = $('#email').val();
$.post('process_info.php', { email: email }, function(callback) { 
    $('#email_feedback').html(callback);
    if(callback == 'awesome') {
        $('#submit').removeClass('hidden');
        $('#quiz_sub').submit(function() {
            $.post('submit_info.php', { email: email }, function(insert_callback) { 
                //want redirection to happen here
            });
        });
    }
});
});
```

any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [change url and redirect in jquery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/846954/change-url-and-redirect-in-jquery)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 //want redirection to happen here
 window.location.href = "http://www.google.com/"
```

or [How to redirect to another webpage in JavaScript/jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/503093/how-can-i-make-a-redirect-page-in-jquery)

Edit: it look like your callback is not executed... alert it or log to console like Rosario suggests, is not working, continue debug:

```
alert(callback);
if(callback == 'awesome') {
    $('#submit').removeClass('hidden');
    $('#quiz_sub').submit(function() {
        alesrt('submiting...');
        $.post('submit_info.php', { email: email }, function(insert_callback) { 
            //want redirection to happen here
            alert('before redirect...');
            window.location = "http://stackoverflow.com";
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: yeah i have tried both of those but for some reason they are not working,
 i have tried both the relative link and direct link

Comment: is your callback function is executed ? alert it or log to console like Rosario suggests.

Comment: the alert is not working, it is initially just resetting the page

Comment: fixxed it? i changed submit() method to click() and it works fine now! Im not sure if it is proper convention, but I cant think of anything else

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
$(location).attr('href', redirect_page);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
window.location.href = 'http://google.com';
```

Answer (score 0):

First check if you are getting to the final process.

```
    $('#quiz_sub').submit(function() {
        $.post('submit_info.php', { email: email }, function(insert_callback) { 
            //want redirection to happen here
            alert("your there!");
            window.location = "http://stackoverflow.com";
        });
    });
```

Then add the redirect. Use window.location ="http://stackoverflow.com";