# Incrementally increasing number in URL - JavaScript

Tags: javascript, pagination

I have a URL like `http://blog.com/post/1` and I need a function which updates the number at the end of it, for pagination.

So far I have:

```
window.location(document.URL++);
```

Comment: What is URL++ ? Is URL a variable name?

Comment: Please add more details.

Comment: @harsha No I was trying to use document.URL to get the current URL.

Comment: Not sure why this was voted down?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var url  = window.location.href.split('/'),
    page = parseInt(url.pop(), 10);

// to go to next page, increment page number and join with URL

window.location.href = url.join('/') +'/'+ (++page);
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/HVagh/2/)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with:

```
var url = document.URL;
var pagenumber = url.substr(url.length-1);
window.location = '/post/'+pagenumber++;
```

But it's a hacky, you can do your project struture better to don't need do this.

Comment: @sanjaypoyzer I don't know if getting the number on url is the best way to do. Becouse your code will be restricted to this format. If you need to change url, you need to change lots of code. And you can handle just 1 digit with this.

Comment: @sanjaypoyzer it does not handle pagenumbers with more than one digit.

Comment: incrementing the page number would be a good idea, no use in going to the same page ?

Comment: Ah it's definitely an issue that it doesn't handle pages with more than one digit. Can it be done without this fault?

Comment: Saving the worst for last, `location` is not a function !

Comment: again, you'r right @adeneo, working a lot my eyes are failing with me. Fell free to edit the answer too.

Comment: You can get the "/" and assume, all after '/' is page number, but still wrong.

Comment: @adaneo I was using the code from [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/846954/change-url-and-redirect-using-jquery)

Answer (score 0):

```
var url = window.location.href; /* e.g. http://blog.com/post/1 */
var pagenumberString = url.match(/\d+/)[0];
window.location.href = url.substr(0, url.length - pagenumberString.length)
                       + (parseInt(pagenumberString, 10) + 1);
```

Comment: This seems to skip from 1 to 9 and then not do anything.

Comment: @sanjaypoyzer oops, minor mistake, forgot the + in the regexp. It is working now http://jsfiddle.net/Mellbourn/5NqsT/

Answer (score 0):

Increment the last number in URL (usually the page number) using a bookmark :

```
javascript:url=window.location.href;
newurl=url.replace(/(\d+)([^0-9]*)$/, function(t,x,y){return parseInt(x,10)+1+y});
window.location.href=newurl;
```

Comment: please format your code to increase the readability.