# Detect a URL and change it - Javascript?

Tags: javascript, wordpress

I have a wordpress website which contains over 900 posts. I am affiliate with a number of companies however they have since changed the URL.

How can I detect a URL say `www.abc.com.au` and change it to `www.xyz.com.au` when they are `<a target="_blank">`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Change URL and redirect using jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/846954/change-url-and-redirect-using-jquery)

Comment: any reason why this is being done in JavaScript and not within the PHP side of things? Do your affiliates not care about search engines (I feel like they would)?

Comment: JavaScript is an inappropriate tool for this task; anyone with JavaScript disabled will get dead links, and as @bonesbrigade notes, it will likely harm search engine rankings as well (since most crawlers don't run JavaScript). You'd be better off doing some batch change on your database.

Answer (score 0):

Use Jquery:

```
('a').each(function( ) {
  if($(this).attr("target") == "_blank" && $(this).attr("href") == "www.abc.com.au")
    $(this).attr("href", "www.xyz.com.au");
});
```

I did not test my code.

You can also use modrewrite and .htaccess.

Answer (score -1):

If you need to edit the links in your own posts it might be worth it to see if there is a wordpress bulk-update plugin that suites your needs, but in JavaScript on the page you can do something like

```
$('a[target="_blank"]').each(function() {
    var href = $(this).attr('href');
    if (href.indexOf('www.abc.com.au') > -1) {
        $(this).attr('href', href.replace('www.abc.com.au', 'www.xyz.com.au'));
    }
});
```

which finds all `a` tags with target _blank and then updates the href if it contains the original domain by replacing that string with the new one.