# HTML Forms: Go to the url from the input field

Tags: php, html, forms, refresh

I have a `form`:

```
<form method="post" action="/whatIwroteintotheInputfield">
  <input type="text" onchange="this.form.submit();"></input>
</form>
```

The form is being posted after inserting a value. Now I don't just want to refresh the site, but redirecting to `/whatIwroteintotheInputfield.`

How can I achieve that?

Thanks for reading!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<form method="post" action="yourTextURL">
    <input type="text" id="changeText" value="http://"></input>
</form>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>

<script>
    $("#changeText").on('change', function() {
          var url = $('#changeText').val();
          window.location = url;
    });
</script>
```

For more info, check [on change()](https://api.jquery.com/change/) & [Change URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/846954/change-url-and-redirect-using-jquery)

And, one question from my side. Why you need `<form></form>` then. It can be done without `<form>` too. So, if possible (if no need), then remove `<form></form>`.

Comment: Thanks man! I'm already using jquery so it seems like this is the best solution. Thanks for your answer! :)

Comment: *Glad To Help* `:D :)` @Skalibran