# not redirecting to page on clicking

Tags: javascript, android, jquery

I have an android app. I want to redirect on clicking on an image. I tried using jquery but its not working please help.

This is the code:

```js
$(document).ready(function (){
  $(".add").click(function(){
     window.navigate("https://someurl/");
  });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a class="add" href="https:someurl" class="imgcenter">
    <img class="add" src="ad_v2.jpg"/>
</a>
```

Comment: try using target="_blank" in your a tag

Comment: `window.location.href = "http://example.com";`

Comment: should there be href in anchor tag if you are using jquery to redirect

Comment: I added window.location.href but not working

Comment: why its tagged with angular ???????

Answer (score 0):

Try `window.location=` instead.

```
window.location = "https://someurl.com"
```

Comment: should there be href in anchor tag if you are using jquery to redirect

Answer (score 0):

Did you try this variant 
`window.location.href = "http://example.com/new_url";`

Comment: should there be href in anchor tag if you are using jquery to redirect

Comment: did you try to debug your code? do you invoke function by click?

Comment: yes I tried testing it by clicking the image in the app

Answer (score 0):

window.navigate is not supported by most browsers. Have a look [here](http://help.dottoro.com/ljuhrdju.php).

You should use window.location or window.location.replace() according to your needs. You can find a good explanation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/847130/2190026).

Answer (score 0):

Use `window.location = "http://...";.` I've been coding cross-browser JavaScript for a few years, and I've never experienced problems using this approach.

window.navigate and window.location.href seems a bit odd to me.

**P.S : .navigate() only works in IE.**

Comment: You have issue with specific browser ?

Comment: its an android app

Answer (score 0):

`window.navigate` is NOT supported cross browsers, you can try `location.href` or `window.location.href`

```
<a class="add" href="javascript: void(0)" class="imgcenter"><img src="ad_v2.jpg"/></a>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function (){
  $(".add").click(function(e){
      e.preventDefault(); // Prevent multiple redirection
      location.href = "https://example.com/";
  });
});
</script>
```